# Using Twisted inside a virtualenv

Tags: python, twisted, virtualenv

After activating my virtualenv, installing twisted with `pip install twisted` it isn't using the correct twisted.

Running

```
twistd web --wsgi myapp
```

returns an error referencing `/usr/bin/twistd` instead of what (presumably) should be `path/to/vituralenv/bin/twistd`

running

```
which twistd
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/twistd
```

where as running

```
which python
```

returns

```
path/to/virtualenv/bin/python
```

which seems to me that twisted isn't install correctly, or at all. But if I do

```
pip install twisted
```

it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied. I then tried to see if twisted and twistd were somehow different projects somehow, but everything seems to indicate that they are.

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Output of `pip freeze`

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Admin==1.0.8
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.2.12
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-Security==1.7.4
Flask-Testing==0.4.2
Flask-WTF==0.10.2
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Twisted==14.0.2
WTForms==2.0.1
Werkzeug==0.9.6
Whoosh==2.6.0
aniso8601==0.83
blinker==1.3
itsdangerous==0.24
passlib==1.6.2
py-bcrypt==0.4
pytz==2014.7
requests==2.4.3
six==1.8.0
stripe==1.19.1
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Comment: Try using `path/to/virtualenv/bin/twistd`. `$ /path/to/virtual/bin/twistd web --wsgi myapp`

Comment: when creating this virtual env, have you specified --no-site-packages

Comment: please show us the output of "pip freeze" also

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember if I specified --no-site-packages

Comment: I redid the virtualenv with --no-site-packages, and get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but anyway...

Install twisted into virtualenv (looks like done), then use full path to execute installed twistd:

- just 'twistd --wsgi something' does not works;
- '/home/.../.../virtualenvdir/bin/twistd --wsgi something' works for me.

BTW printing sys.path from script started by 'twistd' shows system PYTHONPATH, not virtualenv PYTHONPATH.